# Android native alarm application sound files: Download and reuse

Tags: android, alarm

I am developing an application and I wanted to use some of the alarm tone files that are in the android native alarm application. Examples are Morning Scent, Melody Alarm, Country Road and so on.

My questions are:
1. Where do I locate these sound files?
2. What is the license for these sound files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are available in the directory of :
/system/media/audio/alarms

About license , I have no idea. Maybe those of Google are ok

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Alarmtones or ringtones as they are by below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

This will show a picker dialog with the list of sounds available. Then on selecting any of them you will get the result and must receive it in `onActivityResult()`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

           alarmTone = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
    }}
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually want to download these files and use them in an application on both IOS and Android. I am really curious to know the location of these sound files in the android source code, and also, if these files can be used in other applications from a licensing perspective.